# What type of mint are mint leaves from supermarkets?

Tags: mint

I know mint is an umbrella term for different types of mint eg peppermint, spearmint, Orange mint and so on.

However when buying mint from say Tesco’s it Sainsbury’s do you know what type of mint it typically contains?

The packaging seems to just say mint.

Thanks

Comment: I work at a place that sells plants, and people's general opinion is that "regular mint" is spearmint. This is in the US though

Answer (score 4):

It is whatever they had on hand. There seems to be a statistically higher chance to get spearmint, but they sell other mints too. From the point of view of the supermarket, the ambiguity is not a bug, it's a feature. They just sell whatever gets delivered.